# Networking Movement not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, multiplayer, unity-networking, unity3d-unet

I am making a multiplayer scene for my dodgeball game and once I have a host and a client running, it spazzes and forces me to control both the host and the client in one window. Here is what I mean:[image]

This is my code managing the network:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;
public class Script4Network : NetworkBehaviour
{

// Use this for initialization
void Start() {

}

void Update()
{
    if (!isLocalPlayer)
    {

      return;

    }
}
}
```

It might have something to do with my lack of understanding LocalAuthority.

Comment: i am unable to understand your question? do your character/player is not moving across network? or else?

Comment: @MohammadFaizanKhan When i start up both the host and the client, I control both players, they do not move independently

Comment: so you want to control both players?

Comment: @MohammadFaizanKhan I don't, I want to control only one of the two players in one window, and in the other window I want to control the other player

Comment: LocalAuthority require for non-player objects. you have problem in player object? right

Comment: @MohammadFaizanKhan yes, the player object is controlled by the firstPersonController script that Unity provided me, I can show you it when I come back from school.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [**isLocalPlayer**](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.NetworkBehaviour-isLocalPlayer.html) in Update

```
// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (!isLocalPlayer)
    {
      return;
    }

    if(lives == 0)
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene("Lose");

    }



    livesText.text = "Lives: " + lives;
}
```

Comment: what is not working? i am unable to understand your code that is controlling(moving ) your player. share that code